# Is NSNotificationCenter necessary to cancel UILocalnotficiation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I want to cancel a UILocalnotification , when i cancel notification still the notification is being fired . I wanted to know do i have to call any delegate method in appdelegate to cancel notification .the code which i am using is executing correctly .but the notification is getting fired .
Should i use NSNotification center which has removeObserver method to cancel uilocalnotification.

Does UILocalnotification fires notification from the app or from the device.

UPDATE - This is how i am scheduling my notification

```
 -(UILocalNotification *)scheduleNotification :(int)remedyID
        {
           NSString *descriptionBody;

           NSInteger frequency;

          UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

            NSLog(@"%d",remedyID);

            descriptionBody =[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];
            frequency = [[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyFrequency"]intValue];

            NSArray *notificationFireDates = [self fireDatesForFrequency:frequency];

            for (NSDate *fireDate in notificationFireDates)
            {
                    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


                    notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                    notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithString:descriptionBody];
                    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
                    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

                    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

                    notif.fireDate = fireDate;

                    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:notif.alertBody,                                         @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey",  [NSNumber numberWithInt:remedyID],kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey,
                                              nil];

                    notif.userInfo = userDict;

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
                }

                return notif;

    }
```

Cancelling notification

```
 - (void)cancelNotification:(int)remedyId
    {
    NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    NSLog(@"Cancelling... Before %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

      for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications)
      {

      int notifRemedyId = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey"]intValue]; 
        NSLog(@"remedyID  : %d",remedyId);
        NSLog(@"notifyId : %d",notifRemedyId);
        if (remedyId == notifRemedyId) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
          }
       }

    NSLog(@"Cancelling... After %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

> NSNotification center which has removeObserver method to cancel uilocalnotification.

NSNotificationCenter has *nothing* to do with UILocalNotification. I'm sorry that they both use "notification" somewhere in their names, but that is just coincidence really.

Answer (score 0):

[scheduledLocalNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will give you the list of all scheduled notifications and use

```
- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

or you can cancel them all using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Edit :

```
NSString *notifRemedyId = @"notifRemedyId";
UILocalNotification  *localnotif=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey", kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey,YOUR_REMEDYID,@"notifRemedyId",nil];
localnotif.userInfo = userDict;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localnotif];
```

Cancel as :

```
for (UILocalNotification *aNotif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {
    if ([[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey: kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey] isEqualToString:@"kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey"]) {
        if (remedyId == [[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey: kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey] intValue]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:aNotif];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: is it compulsory to pass notification as a parameter or can it be a remedyID ..cause i am passing remedyID cause if remedyID is same as notificationID then i am cancelling notification ..but still i am getting notification

Comment: i am comparing remedyID with notifRemedyID ..the first code in EDIT should i add it in schedulenotification and use 2nd code in my cancel notification method ?
I have added my scheduleNotification method